# How to use aggregate functions in Hive on Group by columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

When I try to use a  inbuilt UDF function or my own UDF function on the GroupBy columns as below in hive I seem to be getting error

```
select col1, col2 from xyz group by my_func(col1), col2
```

It keeps complaining `column –col1 not found in group by expression`.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply a function to a column, it is not longer called the same thing. You should name it explicitly using the `as` keyword.

```
select group1, group2 from xyz group by my_func(col1) as group1, col2 as group2;
```

Also, if you're only selecting the columns that you're grouping by, not the actual grouped data, maybe `distinct` would be more appropriate than `group by`?

Answer (score 1):

The call to the aggregate function is in the wrong place. It should be made as follows:

Select my_func(col1),col2 from xyz group by col1,col2

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2 from xyz group by my_func(col1) as col1, col2
```

The basic is that your GROUP BY needs to have all the cols that you have mentioned in SELECT clause.